# Can I add custom css to an mu-plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

When we create Wordpress sites for clients I like to use mu-plugins to add custom stuff to make my job easier.  The main thing I like about mu-plugins is that the client can't shut them off and they're update proof.  That being said.  Can I add simple css to an mu-plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. What kind of CSS? Where should that code be outputted?

Comment: Say I wanted to target the adminbar in the backend and change the color.

Comment: Yes, you can. Are you actually asking _how_ to do it? It wouldn't be any different to a regular plugin, except that MU plugins are a single PHP file only, so you'd need to write the CSS in a PHP function, or store the CSS file somewhere else.

Comment: Ok.  Could you give me a simple example?  I just can't get it to work.  I tried this nice lady's blog, but it didn't work: http://nastia.rocks/how-to-add-css-code-in-mu-plugin/

Comment: Anyone?  I can’t be the only one. I’m not really that revolutionary?  Lol

Answer (score 4):

You can actually put a directory for your style sheet right in the mu-plugins directory. I called mine "my-companies-assets". The tricky part is calling your styles into your mu-plugin.  In your main MU plugin file...

```
// Setup MY AWESOME MU plugin url
// This will help if you switch to multisite some day
if (is_multisite()) {
    define('MY_AWESOME_MU_PLUGIN_URL', network_site_url('/wp-content/mu-plugins', 'relative'));
} else {
    define('MY_AWESOME_MU_PLUGIN_URL', content_url('/mu-plugins'));
}

// Then you can just use wp-enqueue_style like normal
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-mu-styles', MY_AWESOME_MU_PLUGIN_URL.'/my-companies-assets/styles.css', array(), 1 );

/**
 * The rest of your plugin code 
 * goes here
*/
```

Comment: Nice simple solution, but can we not just use the built in 'WPMU_PLUGIN_URL' instead of defining 'MY_AWESOME_MU_PLUGIN_URL' ?